# Using PostgreSQL through SQLAlchemy with Flask

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a build in the example in the code below and I want to replace it with postgresql. What should I do ?

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////Users/bozkurt/Desktop/veritabani.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120))
    password = db.Column(db.String(80))

class bilgi(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    siteAdi = db.Column(db.String(80))
    Aciklama = db.Column(db.String(80))

    #query 
        user = users.query.filter_by(username=usernmae).first()

    #add
        ekle = bilgi(id = id,aciklama=text)
            db.session.add(ekle)
            db.session.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run(debug=False)
```

Love, good day!

Comment: Do you have Postgresql setup etc.? If so, change the DB URI to point to it.

Comment: installed with pip install postgresql . here I go to the database url: postgresql://root:pass@localhost:5432/database  but I get an error like that. The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Comment: There is an error in the query: `username=usernmae`. Also my db uri is `postgresql://user:pass@localhost/database`. Perhaps you need to drop the :5432?